# Pan Image js e css com "mascara" por cima

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou usando um script js para fazer um efeito de "pan image" conforme o link a seguir:

http://gdebrasil.com.br/teste/

O primeiro listado tem uma imagem por cima e por isso não funciona.. o de baixo é o efeito que quero, porém preciso da imagem fazendo uma "máscara".

Tem alguma configuração no js para que o efeito funcione com a movimentação do mouse sem ser em cima da imagem?

Deixei todo o código css e js no html para facilitar a visualização.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, usei o pseudo-elemento after e funcionou.
Vou retirar o teste do ar.

Obrigado a quem visualizou!